# Print mathjs expression with variables substituted

Tags: javascript, math, mathjs

Is there a way to print the expression string *after* the scope substitutions?

```
var n = math.compile('x * 2');
n.eval({x:2}); // returns 4

// I WISH I could do this:
n.toString({x:2}); // returns '2 * 2'
```

Comment: I could use variable substitution (as commented and deleted), but I feel like it would get complicated solving for all of the permutations of expressions. For example: `'apple*banana + a' {apple: 2, banana: 3, a: 4}`. If mathjs has already solved these, I'd like to use it.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Looking to do something similar. Doesn't look like there's a simple way. Thinking I'll have to write a custom function, iterate through the nodes, and if the node is a SymbolNode then evaluate it using the scope...

Answer (score 0):

It is first necessary to understand the way that MathJS parses to Expression Trees, and the different types of nodes used.
You can read more [here in the docs](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/expression_trees.html).

Algebraic variables get parsed as SymbolNodes. These will need to be substituted for their values. The simplest way to do this would be to use the **transform** function, which is explained in the API further down the page given above.

### From the Docs

> **transform(callback: function)**
>
> Recursively transform an expression tree via a transform function.
> Similar to Array.map, but recursively executed on all nodes in the
> expression tree. The callback function is a mapping function accepting
> a node, and returning a replacement for the node or the original node.
> Function callback is called as callback(node: Node, path: string,
> parent: Node) for every node in the tree, and must return a Node.
> Parameter path is a string containing a relative JSON Path.
>
> The transform function will stop iterating when a node is replaced by
> the callback function, it will not iterate over replaced nodes.
>
> For example, to replace all nodes of type SymbolNode having name ‘x’
> with a ConstantNode with value 3:

```
const node = math.parse('x^2 + 5*x')
const transformed = node.transform(function (node, path, parent) {
  if (node.isSymbolNode && node.name === 'x') {
    return new math.expression.node.ConstantNode(3)
  }
  else {
    return node
  }
})
transformed.toString() // returns '3 ^ 2 + 5 * 3'
```

Comment: There's a shortcoming here... eg if x=3 then 2x get printed as 23, not 2*3. Will look to develop this solution when possible to allow for this.